# How to implement TestNG Listeners in Python test framework?

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver, testng, pytest

I am trying to learn python to work on a test project.
Is there a way to implement TestNG Listeners like functionality in python test framework.

Listeners have method like OnTestFailure(), OnTestSuccess, OnStart(), and many more which are really helpful when you want to do certain things.

Let's say, a test case failed and you want to perform some actions like taking a screenshot. Then you can just write that in one place and not have write that in every afterTest method also.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to do this in python? I am looking for the same. Please let me know.

Comment: This is not there by default in python.
I implemented a class to assert the test case result and then used an if condition to see if the test was successful or not. If the test was not successful, then I am calling the screenshot method.

Comment: @sridhar249 See the answer I posted, I think it should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This class will be called from the test case like this
TestStatus.mark('testName', result, 'message you want to log')
result is a boolean

```py
class TestStatus(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestStatus, self).__init__()

    def mark(self, testName, result, resultMessage):
        testName = testName.lower()
        try:
            if result:
                self.log.info("Verification successful :: " + resultMessage)
            else:
                # If the test fails,
                # this calls screenshot method from util class
                self.util.screenShot("FAIL" + mapKey)
                self.log.info("Verification failed :: " + resultMessage)
        except:
            self.log.info("### Exception Occurred !!!")
            traceback.print_stack()
```

This is a sample test case in the test case class:

```py
def test_accountSignup(self):
    # Generate a username and password to use in the test case
    userName = self.util.getUniqueName()
    password = self.util.getUniqueName()
    # You can ignore this, this is calling a method
    # signup from the account page (page object model)
    self.accounts.signup(userName, password)
    # This call is also from the page object, 
    # it checks if the sign up was successful
    # it returns a boolean
    result = isSignUpSuccessful()
    # test_status object was created in the setUp method
    #
    self.test_status.mark("test_accountSignup", result,
                               "Signup was successful")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sunshine, Thanks for the reply. One question.

I see that, inside the test case function "def test_accountSignup(self)", towards the end of the test case, you added the line

```
self.test_status.mark("test_accountSignup", result,
                               "Signup was successful")
```

What if the test cases fails some where before reaching test_status.mark call in the test case. For eg: What will happen if the test case fails on the line

```
self.accounts.signup(userName, password)
```

I guess, in this case, the test result won't be captured for this particular test case. Correct?

Do you think, we should instead write the test cases as shown below?

```
def test_accountSignup(self):
  try:
   # Write all the test case specific code here
   self.test_status.mark("test_accountSignup", "Passed",
                               "test_accountSignup passed")
  except Exception as e:
     self.test_status.mark("test_accountSignup", "Failed",
                               "test_accountSignup failed. Exception is: "+e.message)
```

Please let me know what you think. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi sridhar249, you might rephrase your answer in a way it is able to stand as answer even if SunShine should decide to delete her answer.

Comment: @sridhar249, Your way is fine, but you don't really need to do that because that should be handled inside self.accounts.signup(userName, password) method. This method should have a try except block.
Other than this, you can catch the result in the tearDown method and then based on the result you can call the test_status.mark(). The benefit of doing this is, that you will have do write the code only in the tearDown method and not repeat the same lines of code in every test method.